# How do i move Map Controls (Zoom In and Out)?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a project that has to do with Google Maps. In some particular states, Zoom controls just get invisible, meaning that some object puts them into the back. Someone helps me to make them always visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoogleMAp.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

By this Thing Zoom control Visible Again
MAy be You do this in
GoogleMAp.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);